# Undo move layer in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, layers, undo-redo

My map projects often incorporate many different layers in many different groups and subgroups.

I keep copies of layers in groups specifically ordered and symbolized for a particular map layout.

Sometimes an errant click "grabs" one of the layers and drops it into a group unintentionally, or moves something out of a group whose contents are expanded.

I've moved entire groups of layers accidentally. The "undo" button does not activate when layers are moved or reordered, but sometimes these inadvertent layer re-orderings are difficult to detect, or to figure out where items were relocated to. Does QGIS 3 provide a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Would something as straight forward as checking the *lock layer* checkbox on the map element property tab fix this?  Any changes to your canvas layer order would not be reflected in the print layout.  Changes to data will be visible in the layout.  Changes to styling can be controlled by the *Lock styles for layers* checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the option to lock layers and styles, but for some folks' workflows it's a bit cumbersome. I'm constantly adjusting symbologies and adding/removing or enabling/disabling layers to refine a map, and to have to adjust these settings within layout view each time I'd like it to refresh interrupts my thought process.

Comment: The issue is more than inconvenience, really. In cases where a project's layers panel has enough layers in it for a vertical scroll bar to appear, even the act of collapsing an expanded group can wreak havoc if the user clicks just long enough for QGIS to think you intend to move that group. A simple "undo" function would solve this issue but so far as I can tell, actions that occur within the layers panel are not eligible actions for the "undo" button (or ctrl-z) to do anything.